# Save textbox as cookies with javascript and print result

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I am new to JavaScript and I need one simple solution.

How to save two text box from first html page, and show it in another html page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to know about using cookies with JavaScript:

- http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

A few practical functions to interact with cookies easier (for example set a cookie in one page, get a cookie in another):

- http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Answer (score 1):

Use `localStorage`: http://jsfiddle.net/usNwP/. `localStorage` is an object of which the values persist among pages on the same domain (so also after reloading, navigating or even rebooting the computer).

```
document.getElementById('save').onclick = function() {
    // save values into localStorage
    localStorage['input1'] = document.getElementById('input1').value;
    localStorage['input2'] = document.getElementById('input2').value;
};

// load textboxes from localStorage (can be on another page)
document.getElementById('input1').value = localStorage['input1'] || "";
document.getElementById('input2').value = localStorage['input2'] || "";
```

Comment: But i don't need only one record to save, maybe I can run this javascipt in next page and for input1 and 2 use data which is entered in textboxes for name and values?

Comment: @Ivan Tanasijevic: You can save on one page and fetch the data on another, so I think it's possible what you want to do (admittedly I can't entirely figure out what you're trying to accomplish).